# Outlook Email Saver

Tags: vba, outlook

I would like to have a macro that I can hit, it reads the email subject line 03100-001-01 and it then saves in that directory on my computer. I just have no idea where to start.

I have no tried anything at this stage

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Subject` property of Outlook items to get the subject string. Then you can use the [InStr](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/library-reference/concepts/getting-started-with-vba-in-office) function which returns a long (number) specifying the position of the first occurrence of one string within another. For example:

```
Dim SearchString, SearchChar, MyPos
SearchString ="XXpXXpXXPXXP"    ' String to search in.
SearchChar = "P"    ' Search for "P".

' A textual comparison starting at position 4. Returns 6.
MyPos = Instr(4, SearchString, SearchChar, 1)    

' A binary comparison starting at position 1. Returns 9.
MyPos = Instr(1, SearchString, SearchChar, 0)

' Comparison is binary by default (last argument is omitted).
MyPos = Instr(SearchString, SearchChar)    ' Returns 9.

MyPos = Instr(1, SearchString, "W")    ' Returns 0.
```

Finally, to save the item you need to use the [MailItem.SaveAs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.saveas) method which saves the Microsoft Outlook item to the specified path and in the format of the specified file type. If the file type is not specified, the MSG format (.msg) is used.

```
Sub SaveAsMsg() 
 Dim myItem As Outlook.Inspector 
 Dim objItem As Object 
 
 Set myItem = Application.ActiveInspector 
 If Not TypeName(myItem) = "Nothing" Then 
   Set objItem = myItem.CurrentItem 
   strname = objItem.Subject 
   'Prompt the user for confirmation 
   Dim strPrompt As String 
   strPrompt = "Are you sure you want to save the item? " & _ 
   "If a file with the same name already exists, " & _ 
   "it will be overwritten with this copy of the file." 
   If MsgBox(strPrompt, vbYesNo + vbQuestion) = vbYes Then 
     objItem.SaveAs Environ("HOMEPATH") & "\My Documents\" & strname & ".msg", olMSG 
   End If 
 Else 
   MsgBox "There is no current active inspector." 
 End If 
End Sub
```

But I'd recommend starting from the following articles to build a basic understanding how VBA macros work:

- [Getting started with VBA in Office](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/concepts/getting-started/using-visual-basic-for-applications-in-outlook)
- [Using Visual Basic for Applications in Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/concepts/getting-started/using-visual-basic-for-applications-in-outlook)